# Current year vs Last year : Filter on ISO week number

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to set up a report on conversions this year vs last year. This formula has worked on another report but cannot show the conversions from last year when applied to this client.

When just filtering on a particular week last year, it shows conversions, so there must be something wrong with my measure.

```
LY Conversion = 
CALCULATE(
SUM('Krogh_Søksrapport'[All_Conversions]), 
PREVIOUSYEAR('Date table'[Date]),
'Date table'[ISOWeeknumber] IN VALUES('Date table'[ISOWeeknumber]))
```

Any obvious errors? I've tried to dismantle it piece by piece but can't find the error.

All help is appreciated :)

UPDATE for Ozan:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQJQs.png)

We have a date table with one-to-many relationship

Date table looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIspu.png)

SOLVED: All we had to do was mark the date table as the the date table, so that the "previousyear"-function used our date table for its date logic.

Comment: What is your logic to use this in the filter argument? Same columns from same table : ''Date table'[ISOWeeknumber] IN VALUES('Date table'[ISOWeeknumber]))'

Comment: Good question Ozan! This worked for me in a different report, there is a page-level relative date filter with last 2 calendar weeks and I want a measure to filter dates with the same ISOweeknumber but for last year. 

So the last two weeks Y=2022 W=38,39
Previous year with ISOweekfilter should be Y=2021 W=38,39

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please share some data, data models, relationships. then I will have something to say.

Comment: @OzanSen, I've updated the post for you. Hopefully this helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All we had to do was

1. mark the date table as the the date table, so that the "previousyear"-function used our date table for its date logic.
2. Thats it!

**Man beat machine this day!**

[image: Visual solution]

Answer (score 0):

Please test this one:

Update()

Version_01

```
LY Conversion =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Krogh_Søksrapport'[All_Conversions] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Date table'[Date], 'Date table'[ISOWeeknumber] ),
        SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( 'Date table'[Date] )
            && 'Date table'[ISOWeeknumber] IN VALUES ( 'Date table'[ISOWeeknumber] )
    )
)
```

Version_02

```
LY Conversion =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Krogh_Søksrapport'[All_Conversions] ),
    CALCULATETABLE (
        ALL ( 'Date table'[Date], 'Date table'[ISOWeeknumber] ),
        SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( 'Date table'[Date] ),
        'Date table'[ISOWeeknumber] IN VALUES ( 'Date table'[ISOWeeknumber] )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately that did not solve the issue. I will continue trying.

Comment: @PeguREM I have updated my post with 2 new solutions. Can you please test them ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, unfortunately they didn't work. I'm gonna put my head down and get to the bottom of this, I'll send you a message if I need your imput, just reply if you have time :)

Comment: Ozan, Great news! There will be a Holiday/Eid season this year after all! We've solved the issue. All we had to do was mark the date table as the the date table, so that the "previousyear"-function used our date table for its date logic. Man beat machine this day!

Comment: Wow! That's just great! You solved your problem yourself. This makes it even more attractive.